# Deleting duplicates in my VBA code is not working... Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

my macro has been giving me this error but I cannot figure it out as I have just started working on this file again after months of absence.

**EXCEL ERROR**: Excel states ***Run-time error '13': Type mismatch*** It seems to be pointing at the *Delete Closed Status* step but the process actually went through.

**ACTUAL FAILURE**:
At the last step, which is deleting all duplicate lines based on the different IDs in column A.

```
Sub Missing_Data_VP()

    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    Dim drg As Range
    With dws.Columns("A:CO").Resize(dws.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set drg = dws.Range("A3:CO" & lCell.Row)
    End With

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = dws.Parent

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Off1")
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws
        Set srg = .Range("F1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    End With

    ' Loop.
    Dim myUnion As Range
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each rrg In drg.Rows
        For Each MyCell In rrg.Cells
            If Not IsError(MyCell.Value) Then ' exclude error values
                If Len(MyCell.Value) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(MyCell.Value, srg, 0)) Then
                        If Not myUnion Is Nothing Then
                            Set myUnion = Union(myUnion, MyCell)
                        Else
                            Set myUnion = MyCell
                        End If
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next MyCell
    Next rrg

    ' Select or inform of failure.
    If myUnion Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing Needs To Be Fixed"
    Else
        myUnion.EntireRow.Select
    End If
    Selection.Cells.Copy
    Worksheets("ETU").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Sorting The ETU
    With Worksheets("ETU").Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Range("A2:BB")
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
     
End With
'Keep columns in last tab
Sheets("ETU").Range("C:G,I:J,BI:CN").EntireColumn.Delete

'Delete Closed status
Dim rng As Range
    Dim pos As Integer
    Set rng = Sheets("ETU").UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("Closed"))
        If pos > 0 Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

'Delete Complete status
    Set rng = Sheets("ETU").UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("Complete"))
        If pos > 0 Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

'Delete Complete status2
    Set rng = Sheets("ETU").UsedRange
    
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK"))
        If pos > 0 Then
            rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
 
'Remove duplicates from column A
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("ETU").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Worksheets("ETU").Range("A1:BB" & LastRow)
MyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End With
    
End Sub
```

Any suggestions or corrections to improve my code would be more than welcome as well.

Have a great day All!

Comment: My guess is that `LCase(rng.Item(i).Value)` is failing if `rng.Item(i).Value` is an errror value.

Comment: What do you mean "Seems to point to the delete closed step" - what specific line is highlighted when the error message pops up? What happens when you hover over the rng variable?

Comment: When I click DEBUG on the error message, this part is highlighted ```pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("Closed"))```

Comment: Try testing `If Not IsError(rng.Item(i).Value) Then` first.

Comment: Hover over `rng.Item(i).Value` when it errors and see what value shows up.

Comment: I just ran the macro again after saving the file in a different location and it seems to work now... Is there a way to combine the three steps Delete closed status, Delete closed status2 and Delete Complete status as one?

Comment: You can use autofilter to show only those values, and then delete the visible rows.   https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+delete+using+autofilter+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: If you use `rng.Item(i).Text` rather than `rng.Item(i).Value` you will get the error message rather than an error value (e.g. `"#DIV/0!"` rather than `Error 2007`) which of course will work properly in the `LCase` function.

Comment: As an improvement I would suggest that you should probably only be checking one column for the "Closed" and "Complete" (and "OKOK...") values- you seem to be scanning the whole sheet and you might well be scanning some parts repeatedly after a line deletion (it's hard to tell).

Comment: That's a good idea Joffan  and it would actually reduce the processing time dramatically. Any idea on how to aim at a specific column?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, the error stopped after closing the VBA window and saving the file to a different location.